# Subtracting one pederssen commitment from another

Tags: elliptic-curves, zero-knowledge-proofs

I am building a range proof to prove that a secret number x lies between a specific range a

prover commits to a values `a<x<b`

prover generates a pedersen commitment to a value `a`

prover generates a range proof to commitment that is commitment from 1 minus 
  commitment from 2

prover sends range proof together with the opening of the commitment from 2

regarding step 3, how do I subtract one commitment from another? is there a better way?

Note: I am using the a javascript implementation to calculate the pederssen commitment
https://github.com/omershlo/simple-bulletproof-js

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly, that given two Perdersen commitments to messages $a$ and $x$ you want to compute a Perdersen commitment to $x-a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I subtract one commitment from another?

Actually, it's surprisingly simple; you subtract the two commitments (and, no, that's not a joke, that's really how you do it).

That is, if we have a commitment $C_1 = x_1G + r_1H$, which is a commitment to the value $x_1$ (you don't know what the values $x_1, r_1$ are, but the prover does.

And, you have a commitment $C_2 = x_2G + r_2H$, which is a commitment to the value $x_2$ (again, known to the prover).

Then, all you do is compute $C_1 - C_2$, that is subtracting these two elliptic curve points.

We have $C_1 - C_2 = (x_1 - x_2)G + (r_1 - r_2)H$; where the prover can compute $x_1 - x_2$ and $r_1 - r_2$, and so this is a valid commitment to the value $x_1 - x_2$ (which the prover can open, should he choose to), which is what you are asking for.

However, I am unfamiliar with the javascript package you're using; I am unable to point you to how you'd do that...

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me ultimately find the solution